# UINavigationController Title Not Using Correct Tint

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I've adjusted the default tint of my navigation bar to be white and it appropriately adjusts the color of each of my navigation bar elements:

[image: Navigation bar with appropriately tinted elements]

However, when I push to a new view controller and try to set the `title` property, the tint is no longer applied:

[image: Navigation bar with inappropriately tinted title]

I know that I can supply a label or something similar to the `titleView` attribute of my view controller that would do the trick, but that's a lot of work (relatively speaking) and in my mind the text should just default to the navigation bar's tint color.  Am I missing something else? Or is this standard behavior that requires a custom `titleView` to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tint property does not affect the color of the title. To set the title color (along with other attributes like font) globally, you can set the `titleTextAttributes` property of the `UINavigationBar` appearance to suit your needs. Just place this code in your AppDelegate or somewhere else appropriate that gets called on launch:

**Swift 3:**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

**Swift 2**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 0):

No you work correctly. But you should to set color for second view. You can use this code to solve your problem.
In second view write this code to set color and font for your navigation title.

---

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = ([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 25)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
```

---

---

Comment: I get that there are other ways to style the text.  My question is specifically whether or not the default behavior of the navigation bar is to display titles in black and ignore any tint settings.

Comment: Looks like your solution is similar to @BJHStudios.  Although his answer explicitly answers mine whereas yours only shows how to set the text attributes.